# Force.com Connected App with OAuth - Edit

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

I'm trying to figure out how to edit a connected app with OAuth usage.

I go to setup -> Manage Appas -> Connected Apps with OAuth Usage

[image]

I see my app, but don't see an edit link.

[image]

I'm the account Admin and have the following permissions enabled:

1. Customize Application
2. Modify All Data
3. Manage Connected Apps

What am I missing?

Is it a permission issue or something else?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Setup > Create > Apps` then scroll to the bottom to see the list of `Connected Apps`.  From there you can edit the settings for a Connected App.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I already did that before posting the question, and the connected app is not showing there.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: If it isn't showing there then maybe you created the Connected App in a different org?